# How to get a record row wise date and datewise last record only display a total effort?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

How to get a record row wise date and `datewise` last record only display a total effort

[image: see here]

```
106 Nishanthi   st1234  Vitakids    yutr    2018-03-19  2018-03-18  Completed   2018-03-18 10:00:00.000 2018-03-18 13:00:00.000 03:00       0.00    0.00    2018-03-19 09:57:34.750 UPS 2018-03-19 09:57:34.750 UPS
107 Nishanthi   st1234  jakel       we      2018-03-19  2018-03-18  Completed   2018-03-18 13:00:00.000 2018-03-18 14:00:00.000 01:00       0.00    0.00    2018-03-19 09:58:48.670 UPS 2018-03-19 09:58:48.670 UPS
108 Nishanthi   st1234  Vitakids    ds      2018-03-19  2018-03-18  Completed   2018-03-18 15:00:00.000 2018-03-19 18:00:00.000 03:00 7 : 0 0.00    0.00    2018-03-19 09:59:21.630 UPS 2018-03-19 09:59:21.630 UPS
 S
```

Comment: Try posting a coherent question.  Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: i need select statement

Comment: for get a datewise record ,date only shown in 1st rec and then last record af the each date has only display the totaleffort